# how to do sorting using java

Tags: java, sorting

I have text file with list of alphabets and numbers. I want to do sorting w.r.t this number using java.

My text file looks like this:

```
a--->12347
g--->65784
r--->675
```

I read the text file and i split it now. But i dont know how to perform sorting . I am new to java. Please give me a idea.

My output want to be

```
g--->65784
a--->12347
r--->675
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

My coding is

```
String str = "";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("counts.txt"));
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
String[] get = str.split("---->>");
```

When i search the internet all suggest in the type of arrays. I tried. But no use.How to include the get[1] into array.

```
    int arr[]=new int[50]
    arr[i]=get[1];
    for(int i=0;i<50000;i++){
                for(int j=i+1;j<60000;j++){
                   if(arr[i]>arr[j]){
                       System.out.println(arr[i]);
                   }
                }
```

Comment: The most practical way is probably use the `Collections.sort()` and a `java.util.TreeMap`, but if you're doing arrays, you will probably do it differently.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [`Arrays.sort()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) or [`Collections.sort()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) methods that allows you to specify a custom `Comparator`, and implement such a Comparator to determine how the strings should be compared for the purpose of sorting (since you don't want the default lexicographic order). It looks like that should involve parsing them as integers.

Answer (score 4):

Your `str.split` looks good to me. Use `Integer.parseInt` to get an `int` out of the string portion representing the number. Then put the "labels" and numbers in a `TreeMap` as described below. The `TreeMap` will keep the entries sorted according to the keys (the numbers in your case).

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap<Integer, String> tm = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
        tm.put(12347, "a");
        tm.put(65784, "g");
        tm.put(675,   "r");

        for (Integer num : tm.keySet())
            System.out.println(tm.get(num) + "--->" + num);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
r--->675
a--->12347
g--->65784
```

From [the API for `TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Comment: +1 for giving out an example code. While people are against this, it is still very suitable for new programmers to see and use the coding pattern. || As a footnote, you should just use `import java.util.TreeMap;` as opposed to a wildcard, `*`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and print its content with iterator for keys. You may have to implement your own [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 0):

rather than give you the code, I would point you on the following path: [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). Read, learn, implement

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

1) convert the numbers into integers
2) Store them in a collection
3) use [Collections.sort()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) to sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are an absolute beginner.

You are correct till the split part. 
You need to place the split number immediately into a string or object (custom object)

You would create something like:

```
class MyClass //please, a better name, 
{
   //and better field names, based on your functionality
   int number;
   String string;
}
```

Note: You have to implement [equals](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [hashCode](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())

After the split (your first snippet), create an object of this class, place `get[0]` into string and `get[1]` into number (after converting the string to integer)

You place this object into an [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Now you have a sorted list.

I have deliberately not specified the details. Feel free to google for any term/phrase you dont understand. By this way you understand, rather than copy pasting some code.